# pass arg to ros node in launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i properly pass argument to ros node in ros launch file?
Here is the ros node which i want to launch from a roslaunch file:

```
> <launch>   <node name="2d_obj_rec"
> pkg="advanced_vision_pkg"
> type="2d_obj_rec" args="image"
>     output="screen"/> </launch>
```

Here i want to pass image arugment like " `rosrun advanced_vision_pkg 2d_obj_rec image:=/camera/image"`
when i launch the file using cmd `" roslaunch advanced_vision_pkg 2d_obj_rec.launch image:=/camera/image"` it is not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340446/pass-arg-to-ros-node-in-launch-file/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2019-12-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add below arg line to launch file

Then Change the node line to the following

---

Originally posted by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) with karma: 195 on 2019-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2019-12-20**:
is this also possile to pass more than one args to more than one ros nodes? how?

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2019-12-20**:
Can you please clarify the question. If you want to pass more arguments to your node the. You can do it by adding more arg tags like blow

You can do like this for another nodes also

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2019-12-20**:
ok. got it.